# Moving a variable in my fragment shader makes it either not work or completely crash my PC

Tags: crash, glsl, gpu, vulkan, fragment-shader

When running on a Radeon HD 7750 and declaring `thisMaterialsource` at `(A)`, the program either crashes or freezes the PC to the point I have to power cycle the machine. It works fine when it's declared at position `(B)`. When running on a Geforce GTX 1070, it works fine in both cases.

```
void main()
{
    vec3 ambientSum = vec3(0);
    vec3 diffuseSum = vec3(0);
    vec3 specSum = vec3(0);
    vec3 ambient, diffuse, spec;

    // (A) - doesn't work when declared/set here  <----------------------------------------
    // Material thisMaterialsource = materialBanks[0].bank.materials[materialId];

    if (gl_FrontFacing)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<light.activeLights; ++i)
        {
            calculateLight(i, inWorldPos.xyz, inNormal.xyz, ambient, diffuse, spec);
            ambientSum += ambient;
            diffuseSum += diffuse;
            specSum += spec;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i=0; i<light.activeLights; ++i)
        {
            calculateLight(i, inWorldPos.xyz, -inNormal.xyz, ambient, diffuse, spec);
            ambientSum += ambient;
            diffuseSum += diffuse;
            specSum += spec;
        }
    }
    ambientSum /= light.activeLights;

    // (B) - works when declared/set here <----------------------------------------
    Material thisMaterialsource = materialBanks[0].bank.materials[materialId];

    vec4 texColor = thisMaterialsource.baseColorFactor;
    if(thisMaterialsource.colorTextureIndex > -1){ texColor = texture(texSampler[thisMaterialsource.colorTextureIndex], inUV0)  * thisMaterialsource.baseColorFactor; }

    vec4 emissive = thisMaterialsource.emissiveFactor;
    if (thisMaterialsource.unlitTextureIndex > -1) {
        emissive = texture(texSampler[thisMaterialsource.unlitTextureIndex], inUV0) * thisMaterialsource.emissiveFactor;
    }

    outColor = vec4(ambientSum + diffuseSum, 1) * texColor + vec4(specSum, 1) + emissive;
}
```

Full shader code:

```js
#version 450
#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable
#extension GL_EXT_nonuniform_qualifier : require

struct LightInfo
{
    vec3 Position;//Light Position in eye-coords
    vec3 La;//Ambient light intensity
    vec3 Ld;//Diffuse light intensity
    vec3 Ls;//Specular light intensity
};

struct MaterialInfo
{
    vec3 Ka;//Ambient reflectivity
    vec3 Kd;//Diffuse reflectivity
    vec3 Ks;//Specular reflectivity
    float Shininess;//Specular shininess factor
};

struct Material{
    vec4 baseColorFactor;
    vec4 emissiveFactor;
    float metallicFactor;
    float roughnessFactor;
    float normalScale;
    float occlusionStrength;

    int colorTextureIndex;
    int normalTextureIndex;
    int unlitTextureIndex;
    int ambientOcclusionTextureIndex;
    int metallicRoughnessTextureIndex;

    int isTwoSided;
    int alphaMode;
    float alphaCutoff;
};

struct MaterialBank{
    Material materials[80];
};

struct LightData{
    vec4 pos;
    vec4 color;
};


#define MAX_CAMERAS 16

struct CameraData{
    vec4 pos;
    mat4 mat;

    mat4 view;
    mat4 proj;
    mat4 clip;
};

layout(push_constant) uniform PushConsts {
    uint cameraIndex;
    uint time;
} pushConsts;

layout(binding = 0) uniform UniformBufferCamera {
    CameraData cameras[MAX_CAMERAS];
    uint cameraCount;
    uint cameraMax;
} cam;

layout(binding = 1) uniform UniformBufferLight {
    LightData lights[16];

    vec4 ambientColor;

    int activeLights;
} light;

layout(set=1, binding = 0) uniform sampler2D texSampler[32];
layout(set=2, binding = 0) uniform UniformBufferMat {
    MaterialBank bank;
} materialBanks[1];

layout(location = 0) in vec4 inNormal;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 inUV0;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 inUV1;
layout(location = 3) in vec4 inWorldPos;
layout(location = 4) in flat uint materialId;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 outColor;

void calculateLight(int lightIndex, vec3 position, vec3 norm, out vec3 ambient, out vec3 diffuse, out vec3 spec)
{
    LightData thisLightSource = light.lights[lightIndex];
    Material thisMaterialsource = materialBanks[0].bank.materials[materialId];

    LightInfo thisLight;
    thisLight.Position = thisLightSource.pos.xyz;//Light Position in eye-coords
    thisLight.La = light.ambientColor.rgb;//Ambient light intensity
    thisLight.Ld = thisLightSource.color.rgb;//Diffuse light intensity
    thisLight.Ls = thisLightSource.color.rgb;//Specular light intensity

    MaterialInfo thisMaterial;

    vec4 texColor = thisMaterialsource.baseColorFactor;
    if (thisMaterialsource.colorTextureIndex > -1){ texColor = texture(texSampler[thisMaterialsource.colorTextureIndex], inUV0) * thisMaterialsource.baseColorFactor; }

    vec4 mrSample = vec4(1);
    if (thisMaterialsource.metallicRoughnessTextureIndex > -1) { mrSample = texture(texSampler[thisMaterialsource.metallicRoughnessTextureIndex], inUV0); }

    float perceptualRoughness = mrSample.g * thisMaterialsource.roughnessFactor;
    float metallic = mrSample.b * thisMaterialsource.metallicFactor;

    thisMaterial.Ka= texColor.rgb * (metallic+perceptualRoughness)/2;//Ambient reflectivity
    thisMaterial.Kd= texColor.rgb * (perceptualRoughness);//Diffuse reflectivity
    thisMaterial.Ks= texColor.rgb * (metallic-perceptualRoughness);//Specular reflectivity
    thisMaterial.Shininess= (metallic);//Specular shininess factor

    vec3 n = normalize(norm);
    vec3 s = normalize(thisLight.Position - position);
    vec3 v = normalize(-position);
    vec3 r = reflect(-s, n);

    ambient = thisLight.La * thisMaterial.Ka;

    if (thisMaterialsource.ambientOcclusionTextureIndex > -1){
        float ao = texture(texSampler[thisMaterialsource.ambientOcclusionTextureIndex], inUV0).r;
        ambient = ambient * ao;
    }

    float sDotN = max(dot(s, n), 0.0);
    diffuse = thisLight.Ld * thisMaterial.Kd * sDotN;

    spec = thisLight.Ls * thisMaterial.Ks * pow(max(dot(r, v), 0.0), thisMaterial.Shininess);
}

void main()
{
    vec3 ambientSum = vec3(0);
    vec3 diffuseSum = vec3(0);
    vec3 specSum = vec3(0);
    vec3 ambient, diffuse, spec;

    // (A) - doesn't work when declared/set here  <----------------------------------------
    // Material thisMaterialsource = materialBanks[0].bank.materials[materialId];

    if (gl_FrontFacing)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<light.activeLights; ++i)
        {
            calculateLight(i, inWorldPos.xyz, inNormal.xyz, ambient, diffuse, spec);
            ambientSum += ambient;
            diffuseSum += diffuse;
            specSum += spec;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i=0; i<light.activeLights; ++i)
        {
            calculateLight(i, inWorldPos.xyz, -inNormal.xyz, ambient, diffuse, spec);
            ambientSum += ambient;
            diffuseSum += diffuse;
            specSum += spec;
        }
    }
    ambientSum /= light.activeLights;

    // (B) - works when declared/set here <----------------------------------------
    Material thisMaterialsource = materialBanks[0].bank.materials[materialId];

    vec4 texColor = thisMaterialsource.baseColorFactor;
    if(thisMaterialsource.colorTextureIndex > -1){ texColor = texture(texSampler[thisMaterialsource.colorTextureIndex], inUV0)  * thisMaterialsource.baseColorFactor; }

    vec4 emissive = thisMaterialsource.emissiveFactor;
    if (thisMaterialsource.unlitTextureIndex > -1) {
        emissive = texture(texSampler[thisMaterialsource.unlitTextureIndex], inUV0) * thisMaterialsource.emissiveFactor;
    }

    outColor = vec4(ambientSum + diffuseSum, 1) * texColor + vec4(specSum, 1) + emissive;
}
```

Please excuse the quality of my shader code, I'm just experimenting and cobbling stuff together, and came upon this issue that, aside from being annoying to debug, completely blindsided me.

It's fixed now, but I'd like to know why it happened and honestly, unlike lots of other issues I've dealt with while learning, I don't even know where to start looking.

Is this simply a bug in GPU/drivers or a manifestation of some profound and arcane machinations that dictate how shaders work? How can I debug this sort of issues? Is there a way to see this is going to fail, other than running it? I'd really like to know, I care much more about learning from this than just getting it to run.

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with your shader in its two forms to me. It might have been a driver bug. GPU drivers are very complex things and they have bugs much like other software.

Comment: You may want to contact the driver vendor (AMD?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind going through one or two more power-off-on cycles, try the following simplification for your shader:

```
void main()
{
    ... variables

    // (A) - doesn't work when declared/set here  <----------------------------------------
    // Material thisMaterialsource = materialBanks[0].bank.materials[materialId];

    /// Instead of doing two almost identical loops, extract the normal inversion
    vec3 normal = (gl_FrontFacing ? inNormal : -inNormal).xyz;
    for (int i=0; i<light.activeLights; ++i)
    {
        calculateLight(i, inWorldPos.xyz, normal, ambient, diffuse, spec);
        ambientSum += ambient;
        diffuseSum += diffuse;
        specSum += spec;
    }
    ambientSum /= light.activeLights;

    // (B) - works when declared/set here <----------------------------------------
    Material thisMaterialsource = materialBanks[0].bank.materials[materialId];

    ... all the rest
}
```

A wild guess might be the following: the HD7750 is relatively old and two loops over (dynamic number) of active lights can generate too much shader bytecode, if the GLSL compiler does something strange. So you get an overflow of available thread memory. The GTX 1070 is obviously much more powerful and would not suffer from an "abuse" like this.

Other than this, the shader should be fine and the above change is still a workaround, not a must. We have encountered strange behavior (i.e., somehting not working contrary to the spec) of GLSL even on newer Radeons, but it was not similar to your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I had a quick look and yeah, your suggestion reduced the spir-v output from 13,4kB to 12,6kB. Moving the declaration has no effect on final binary size though. I guess it's safe to assume that spir-v bytecode is then translated to whatever the GPU/driver uses internally, so it's not really an indicator of anything.

Comment: Since the HD7750 is a very old card, maybe the crash is due to the amount of variables that declaration unrolls to? Decompiled code shows the contents of the `Material` struct declared as separate variables there. Perhaps having that at the "beginning" of the shader is too much, while putting it at the bottom is somehow less overwhelming for that old GPU.

Still, my main question is how can I spot that kind of an issue? Can a tool like the Radeon GPU Analyzer help identify a problem like this? I used it to look at the shader code and I couldn't spot anything alarming in either variant.

Comment: Maybe I'm not very clear, but you have got the right idea - basically, there are too many variables caused by loop unrolling. Spotting these kinds of issues is a matter of practice (of fixing such issues...) and obeying some general "best practices" while coding shaders. You have done everything right by moving stuff here and there, getting a fair share of reboots and finally applying a small code reduction. If you have something complex (such a shader _is_ complex for a GPU thread), break it down into smaller parts. Most of the time heavy-weight analyzers are not needed.